# Natural deduction, from premise: $\,\lnot p \lor \lnot q,\,$ to conclusion : $\,\lnot(p \land q)$

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

What's the natural deduction of this exercise?

> Premise:  $\lnot p \lor \lnot q$
>   Conclusion: $\lnot(p\land q)$

I must have something like the following, but I do not know how to start.

[image]

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Comment: Slide 11 here: http://www.sfs.uni-tuebingen.de/~gjaeger/lehre/ws0910/mathe/slides16.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof sketch:

1. $\lnot p \lor \lnot q$ (premise)
2. $\quad |\underline{\text{(Assume)}\; p\land q}\;$ (Assumption)
3. $\quad |\;p\;$ ("$\land$-elimination")
4. $\quad |\; q\;$ (simplification/$\land$-elimination)
5. $\qquad |\underline{\;\; \lnot p\;}$ (assumption)
6. $\qquad | \;\;p \land \lnot p\;$ $\land$-Intro (3, 6)
7. $\qquad | \;\;$ Contradition. (6)
8. $\qquad | \underline{\;\; \lnot q\;}$ (assumption)
9. $\qquad | \;\;q\land \lnot q\;\;\land$-Intro (4, 8)
10. $\qquad | \;\;$Contradiction (9)
11. $\quad |\;\;$ Contradiction $\lor$-Elimination (1, 5-10)
12. $\lnot (p\land q)$ (2-10). Our assumption $p\land q$ leads to a contradiction, so that $\lnot(p \land q)$ is therefore true.

Comment: Sophie, the last step, 12 (conclusion) is justified by "negation introduction".